# Linq error: "string[] does not contain a definition for 'Except'."

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my code:

```
    public static string[] SplitKeepSeparators(this string source, char[] keptSeparators, char[] disposableSeparators = null)
    {
        if (disposableSeparators == null)
        {
            disposableSeparators = new char[] { };
        }

        string separatorsString = string.Join("", keptSeparators.Concat(disposableSeparators));
        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(source, @"(?<=[" + separatorsString + "])");

        return substrings.Except(disposableSeparators); // error here
    }
```

I get the compile time error `string[] does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload ... has some invalid arguments`.

I have included `using System.Linq` in the top of the source file.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `substrings` variable is a `string[]`, but `disposableSeparators` is a `char[]` - and [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) works on two sequences of the same type.

Either change `disposableSeparators` to a `string[]`, or use something like:

```
return substrings.Except(disposableSeparators.Select(x => x.ToString())
                 .ToArray();
```

Note the call to `ToArray()` - `Except` just returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, whereas your method is declared to return a `string[]`.

Comment: Thank! Error message is misleading. It makes you think that the lib is not accessible, when it fact the problem with parameter type.

Comment: @MikeKeskinov: What makes you think it's not *accessible*? The error message seems entirely reasonable to me - in particular, it mentions arguments, but nothing to do with access...

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are using `.Except<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> other)` with two different types for T (`string` and `char`). Change your delimiters to a string array if you want to use Except.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx